# SQL Server - Selectively inserting fields into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing a SP within a SP. The SP returns say 10 params. I am interested in only 5 of them. How do I insert only these 5 into the temp table.

The code I have so far:

```
  DECLARE @tmpUnion TABLE
  (
    UnionCode VARCHAR(10),
    UnionDate DATETIME,
    UnionPosition VARCHAR(30),
    UnionInitFees BIT,
    UnionDues BIT
  )

  --getDetails returns 10 params. I need only these 5
  INSERT INTO @tmpUnion
  (UnionCode, UnionDate, UnionPosition, UnionInitFees, UnionDues)
  EXEC getDetails
        @iUserId = @OriginalLoginId
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the result of getDetails into a tablevar that contains all of the return values, then do your insert off of the additional table.

You might also [check out this site](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for more information on how to share data between stored procedures.

Comment: I lied when I said the getDetails returns 10 values. Actually, it returns more than 50. If possible I want to avoid the additional overhead of creating a temp table with all these columns

Answer (score 2):

Use OPENROWSET like so:

```
Select 
       *
from OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','Data Source=Server_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;
      Integrated Security=SSPI','Execute yourdb..get_orders')
```

Now you can easily filter the resultset

```
Select 
employeeid,orderid,orderdate 
from 

OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','Data Source=Server_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;
       Integrated Security=SSPI','Execute yourdb..get_orders')

where
       orderdate>='19960101' and orderdate<'19970101'
```

You don't need to create a temp table and you also don't need to worry about the structure of the procedure.

[Found here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/11/26/select-columns-from-exec-procedure-name-is-this-possible.aspx)

EDIT: Final solution moved from comments after discussion.

Comment: #TempTable creates a global table right? When I declare this, I don't need to specify the columns and the datatypes?

Comment: Double hash (##) creates global table.
You will need to know the structure of the result set.
I think I worked around this recently, I'll have to find the code.

Comment: I am, of course, assuming that you don't have access to the stored procedure or for some other reason cannot modify it.

Comment: True, I cant modify the callee SP

Comment: I found an awesome solution to your problem.  I'm not sure it is the same thing I did a few months back - I still haven't found it.
Look here: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/11/26/select-columns-from-exec-procedure-name-is-this-possible.aspx

Comment: 2nd solution, in case you are like me and reject it after reading the first few sentences.

Comment: I'm a new user, so I don't yet know how to use this site to its fullest potential.  The link I provided should probably be on the main page of this question instead of buried in the comments because it is almost certainly the best solution.

Comment: WakeUPScreaming - AFAIK, the OpenRowSet requires a connection string. This is an enterprise app that has the connection string tucked away in the config files.

Comment: I think if the DBA gave you the name of the stored proc, they might give you a basic connection string.  Worth a try.

Comment: Check out the docs for OPENROWSET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(SQL.90).aspx
Also consider that your stored procedure should be able to get the values needed for the parameters by querying its running context.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. The table variable must match exactly the structure of waht is being returned.

Comment: A better answer would show the way instead of just saying "you can't"