# Insert result into temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

So I've read these posts

- [Using a Variable in OPENROWSET Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831472/using-a-variable-in-openrowset-query)
- [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

And with that I came up with this solution

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

alter procedure [CP24SHOP].[spSearch_DitoNr_OemNr_EngineType]
    @user           nvarchar(255),
    @ditoNr         int,
    @oemNr          nvarchar(255) = null,
    @engineType     nvarchar(255) = null
as
begin
    if(@oemNr is null and @engineType is null)
        exec CP24SHOP.spSearchDitoNr
            @user = @user,
            @ditoNr = @ditoNr
    else
        begin
            declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT *  
                                        FROM OPENROWSET(
                                            ''SQLNCLI'', 
                                            ''Server=localhost\ISTABGLOBAL;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
                                            ''exec CP24SHOP.spSearchDitoNr
                                                @user = ' + @user + ',
                                                @ditoNr = ' + @ditoNr + ''')'

            --exec (@sql)

            SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM (@sql) -- Line 33
                where OEMNumber = @oemNr
        end
end
return 0;
```

however upon running this scripts I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spSearch_DitoNr_OemNr_EngineType, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any idea of whats wrong with my syntax cause for me this is new territory

**EDIT**
What I'm trying to do is to call a stored procedure `CP24SHOP.spSearchDitoNr` and then only select those rows where `OEMNumber = @oemNr`

Comment: You should identify line 33 referred to in the error message.  As writting, the last `SELECT` makes no sense at all, but the commented out `exec` suggests that you understand this.

Comment: Looks like you're missing `'` around `+@user` at least - so I think the problem comes down to your `@sql` string not being build correct as well as what Gordon mentions with the `SELECT`

Comment: and if your `@user` is indeed a varchar, you miss an `' ` before and after

Comment: I've tried  changing ´@user = ' +@user + ',´ into ´@user = ''' +@user + ''',´ I still get the same error message

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM (@sql)` because `@sql` is a `nvarchar(max)`. You need to save the values from your `OPENROWSET` query into a table.

For more information have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622940/insert-into-table-exec-query-with-sql-server-2000). You can use `INSERT INTO myTable EXEC sp_executesql(@sql)`.

Comment: But doesn't that require me to know what variables there are in my table?

Comment: Yes, it requires you to specify the fields for your table.

Comment: hmm I see... What if I'm unable to do that?

Comment: This problem is discussed in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642666/dynamically-create-temp-table-based-on-resultset-from-sp). And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630584/sql-server-selectively-inserting-fields-into-temp-table) is also a post about `OPENROWSET`.